Search and select file in opened folder
I found a script and modified it to search for a filename in a folder and select the filename.
This code works fine when I use Shell "explorer.exe /select,""" & FilePath & """", vbNormalFocus to open the folder and select the filename. However, it keeps opening a new folder instance instead of using the currently opened folder.
I tried to use this code:
If confirmfolder Then
   Wnd.Visible = True
   oShell.Open FolderPath & "\"
   ShellExecute 0, "Select", FilePath, vbNullString, vbNullString, vbNormalFocus

However, it does not select the filename in the folder at all. I'm not sure which part goes wrong, or maybe someone can help with this.
Below is my script.
Dim FolderPath As String
Dim PartialFilename As String
Dim FileFound As String
Dim FileSystem As Object
Dim Folder As Object
Dim File As Object
 
FolderPath = Worksheets("Automation").Range("H3").Value
PartialFilename = Format(Amount, "#,##0.00")


   Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Set Folder = FileSystem.GetFolder(FolderPath)
   For Each File In Folder.Files
       If InStr(1, File.Name, PartialFilename, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
           FileFound = FolderPath & "\" & File.Name
           Call SelectFileInExplorer(FileFound)
           GoTo nextshow
       End If
   Next File
   Set FileSystem = Nothing
   Set Folder = Nothing



 Option Explicit
#If VBA7 And Win64 Then
   Declare PtrSafe Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As LongPtr
#Else
   Declare PtrSafe Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As LongPtr
#End If

Sub SelectFileInExplorer(FilePath As String)
   Dim FolderPath As String
   Dim confirmfolder As Boolean
   Dim oShell As Object
   Dim Wnd As Object
   
   FolderPath = Left(FilePath, InStrRev(FilePath, "\") - 1)
   confirmfolder = False
   Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
   For Each Wnd In oShell.Windows
       If Wnd.Name = "File Explorer" Then
           If Wnd.document.Folder.Self.Path = FolderPath Then
               confirmfolder = True
               Exit For
           End If
       End If
   Next Wnd
   If confirmfolder Then
       Wnd.Visible = True
       oShell.Open FolderPath & "\"
       ShellExecute 0, "Select", FilePath, vbNullString, vbNullString, vbNormalFocus
   Else
       Shell "explorer.exe /select,""" & FilePath & """", vbNormalFocus
   End If
End Sub


Any reason you don't use Application.FileDialog?

I am afraid that all the time a new explorer window will be open. Without killing the previous explores process(es) you will have as many such explorer windows as  many times you try your code. But why do you need this selection? Can you explain what you try accomplishing? I think it may be easier to find other ways to do it and we maybe will help in that direction...

@FunThomas the reason why i’m not using FileDialog because currently i’m trying to search the file in the folder and select the file, but not to open it. This is similar to when we use windows search in the folder, and search based on partial name, then we will click the file(not open)

@FaneDuru What I’m trying to achieve right now is, I have list of amount in excel range, this amount will be partially search in the folder to find if there’s any file name contain the amount, and click on it(not open). This is similar to what we using windows search in folder, and search according to partially name. Now it worked for open new instance, but it not working if the folder already opened, meaning it still open as new instance. Sorry for my bad english

I am afraid I still do not understand what finally you try accomplishing... Why selecting? It is easy to check if a specific string (amount, I would say...) is part of a file name located in a specific folder. Automatically, without opening anything. So, WHY SELECTING? What would you do with that selected file, WHICH CANNOT BE DONE IN VBA (faster)?

@FaneDuru I don’t have any issue with checking and yes that one is easy to do it. Selecting without opening meaning when user go to the folder, the system already select the file found, so they don’t have to scroll down, or searching for the file name like they used in windows search in that folder. For without opening the file, because they search name partially, when selecting the file, they can still read the full file name and then they can proceed to open the file or not. Like i said, it worked perfectly using Shell explorer select but it kept opening new instance

So, understanding that you want selecting as the last option of a search procedure, would it be a correct understanding? Even if I do not understand what the user can visually better do/analize which VBA cannot, but I can take it like this... As I said in my first comment, you cannot do that using a command line without opening a new explorer window. And I also said that you can overpass this problem killing the previously open window (in this way). The user will  not see any difference in doing that (possible) instead of selecting in the previous explorer windows (not possible).

The catch would be to obtain the previous window process ID. Which is not so complicated using part of your above code. It extra needs to determine that window handle and based on it the respective process ID (PID), based on which to be killed before a new trial. Now, do you always need to do that for the same folder path? If so, it is easy to extract from the new file full name and kill it. If not, I mean searching in different folders will need memorizing the respective PID and preliminarily killing based of this. Placing in a variable is volatile and it may be lost in case of VBA errors

Please, test the next solution able to kill the previous used Explorer window process and only after that selecting a new file:

Copy the next API function on top of a standard module:

Option Explicit

Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowThreadProcessId Lib "user32" _
                  (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, lpdwProcessId As Long) As Long


For the case of searching/selecting files in different folders (needing to memorize the previously open explorer window process):

Sub testSelectFileTheSameExplorerWindow()
   'shell "explorer.exe /select,""" & ThisWorkbook.path & """", vbNormalFocus 'it works
   Dim ret, FilePath As String: FilePath = ThisWorkbook.fullname 'just an example...
   Dim procPID As String, clngPID As Long

   'check if a (stil valid) PID has been memorized and kill that process, if yes:
   If Dir(procPID) <> "" Then
      KillProcbyPID CLng(CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(procPID, 1).ReadAll)
   End If
   
   ret = shell("explorer.exe /select,""" & FilePath & """", vbNormalFocus)   
   If ret <> 0 Then 'ret only confirms that above shell line does what it should
     clngPID = FindSpecificExplorerProc(FilePath) 'determine the PID of the last open Explorer window
     'memorize the above found PID:
     CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile(procPID).Write clngPID
   Else
     MsgBox "Something wrong happened and Shell could not select """ & FilePath & """ file"
   End If
End Sub

Sub KillProcbyPID(PID As Long)
 Dim strComputer As String, objWMIService As Object, colProcessList As Object, objProcess As Object
 strComputer = "."
 Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
 Set colProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
                 ("Select * from Win32_Process Where ProcessID = " & PID)
 For Each objProcess In colProcessList
    objProcess.Terminate 'kill the process by its PID (if this still exists)
 Next
End Sub

Function FindSpecificExplorerProc(fileFullName As String) As Long
   Dim folderPath As String, oShell As Object, Wnd As Object, test_pid As Long
   folderPath = left(fileFullName, InStrRev(fileFullName, "\") - 1)
   Do While test_pid = 0
        Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

        For Each Wnd In oShell.Windows
            If Wnd.name = "File Explorer" Then
                If Wnd.Document.Folder.Self.path = folderPath Then
                    GetWindowThreadProcessId CLngPtr(Wnd.hwnd), test_pid 'it returns the window PID
                    FindSpecificExplorerProc = test_pid 'not exiting, to catch the last explorer window, if more...
                End If
            End If
        Next Wnd
   Loop
End Function


If you need searching al the time in the same folder, the necessary folder (to kill its previously open window process) can be extracted from the files full name and no need to previously memorize the the previous window process ID

Sub testSelectFileTheSameExplorerWindowSameFolder()
   'shell "explorer.exe /select,""" & ThisWorkbook.path & """", vbNormalFocus 'it works
   Dim FilePath As String: FilePath = ThisWorkbook.fullname 'just an example...
   
   'Searching for all explorer windows of the same folder and kill their process(es):
   KillExplorerWindowByTitle FilePath 'it kills ALL explorer windows open in the FilePath folder...
   
   shell "explorer.exe /select,""" & FilePath & """", vbNormalFocus
End Sub

Sub KillExplorerWindowByTitle(FilePath As String)
  Dim folderPath As String, oShell As Object, Wnd As Object, test_pid As Long
  folderPath = left(FilePath, InStrRev(FilePath, "\") - 1)
   
   Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
   For Each Wnd In oShell.Windows
       If Wnd.name = "File Explorer" Then
           If Wnd.Document.Folder.Self.path = folderPath Then
               GetWindowThreadProcessId CLngPtr(Wnd.hwnd), test_pid 'test_pid returns the window PID

               KillProcbyPID test_pid 'call the sub killing it...
           End If
       End If
   Next Wnd
End Sub

It uses the same KillProcbyPID Sub...
Please, send some feedback after testing it.

Omg, this worked great!! it closed the opened folder and reopen with selected item. Do you know how can i add when it open the folder, it always in full screen size? Because sometimes it reduce the screens size. Also if you don't mind, could you please explain a bit what is this GetWindowThreadProcessId CLngPtr(Wnd.hwnd), test_pid and KillProcbyPID test_pid sub?

@sephiroth 1. Instead of vbNormalFocus try using vbMaximizedFocus or 3 (this is the constant value). 2. GetWindowThreadProcessId API has the second parameter as out one. I mean, it returns the process ID (PID) inside this variable. 3. KillProcbyPID kills/terminates the specific process with that PID. It extracts the respective process (by its PID) from Win32_Process collection and kills/terminate it. In this way the explorer window is closed...

@sephiroth GetWindowThreadProcessId API function needs its first parameter as pointer (the explorer window Handle). It transforms the returned Long value in the necessary LongPtr, to match the function requirement...
